# Implement Android Custom Tabbar

Tags: android

I need to develop this layout in android device, im using a tabview and three tabs in the design. TabWidget need to bottom of the screen and also i need a way to develop this kind of layout for tabwidget.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try out this way to get the `TabWidget` at the bottom of the screen:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>     <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_weight="1" />
>     <TabWidget
>         android:id="@android:id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center|center" 
>         android:tabStripEnabled="false"/>        
> </LinearLayout>
> ```